# QT 4 - How to build QuaZip and QtCrypto to .Lib?

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, quazip

**Latest news:**

1. I fixed QuaZip issue
2. The QtCrypto is work on Desktop platform (with AES 256) now. But how to **build the lib for Symbian**?

**Questions:**

1. How do I Build the .lib file of QtCryptoand QuaZip ? (details as below)
2. How to Use the Lib in a new QT Mobile Application Project (QT Create 2.3) ?

   **Background:**
3. I am using Qt Creator to make an UnZip Manager App for Nokia Symbian device.
4. I need to use QtCrypto (decrypt the file) and QuaZip (unzip the ePub zip file)
5. I cannot use them in my project.

**Platform:**

1. Qt Creator 2.3.0 base on Qt 4.7.4
2. Window 7 32bit
3. Deploy to Nokia N8

**Step i tried:**

***A) Build Lib***

1. Download and open the QtCtypto and QuaZip project

   > QtCtypto: http://delta.affinix.com/qca/
   >
   > QuaZip: http://quazip.sourceforge.net/
2. Open it without any change. Click "Build"
3. Cannot find the .lib file. So i copy the .dll and .h instead
4. Still fail even if i follow the instruction of QuaZip website

***B) Import to project***

1. I create new Project (Mobile Qt Application)
2. Choosed "Symbian Simulator" ,"Symbian Device" ,"Window desktop" build environment
3. Import the above-mentioned .dll .h files.
4. Import the zdll.lib, zlib.def (It's come with QuaZip project)
5. Add below code in .pro file

```
 OTHER_FILES += \    
 lib/zdll.lib \    
 lib/zlib.def \    
 lib/QuaZip.dll


 LIBS += $$PWD/lib/zdll.lib    
 LIBS += $$PWD/lib/QuaZip.dll   

 INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/include    
 DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/include
```

6. In the .cpp file, it can detect  and i can create a variable

7. I follow the example in QuaZip website. Its like: QuaZip(fileName);

8. But when i run the app, it cannot start up. But no error when i build it

***C) Others***

1. I try to build .lib from QuaZip and QtCtypto but fail
2. It always build .dll or .a but not .lib

Comment: can you share how you compile QuaZip for Symbian. I also need it for my project. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I needed QuaZip, badly. Here's SConscript file I made to build it:

```
# SConscript

env = Environment (tools = ['default', 'qt4'])
env.Tool ('qt4')
env.Append (CPPFLAGS = ['-O2'], CPPDEFINES = ['QT_NO_DEBUG', 'QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT'])
if (env ['PLATFORM'] == 'win32'):
        env.Append (CPPPATH = [env ['QT4DIR'] + '/src/3rdparty/zlib'])
env.EnableQt4Modules (['QtCore'])
lib_quazip = env.StaticLibrary ('quazip', Glob ('*.cpp') + Glob ('*.c'))
env.Default (lib_quazip)
Export ('lib_quazip')
```

If you're not familiar with [SCons](http://scons.org/), it's a handy remplacement for autotools / makefiles. This SConscript worked on both Windows and Linux, if I remember correctly. You will also need the scons-qt4 plugin (found at [Tools Index](http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsIndex)) Building QtQrypto might or might not be similar.

Comment: Finally, i fixed the QuaZip by myself. But still cannot make use of QtCtypto.  I can build it but it display "AES not supported"......